# Why does Retrofit 2.0.2 fail with "unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.address" when using @Query in POST call?

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I have the following api endpoint defined:

```
@POST("api/ResetPassword")
Call<Envelope> resetPassword(@Query("email") String email);
```

which fails with the error message: "unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.address"

Is there a limitation preventing a query in a POST ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed our endpoint from a POST to a GET and the call now works.

Did I miss the explanation of why @Query and POST don't work together with Retrofit/okhttp ?

Searching on the subject it doesn't appear to be prohibited in general though it might not be best practice.